# Does Artifactory store whole configuration in artifactory.config.latest.xml?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I am using Docker and NuGet repositories in Artifactory. Current [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Configuration+JSON#RepositoryConfigurationJSON-application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.repositories.RemoteRepositoryConfiguration+json) does not support every option on Docker or NuGet repositories.

It looks like the whole configuration created by calling appropriate REST API calls is stored in a file called `artifactory.config.latest.xml`.

Is it safe to restore the whole repository configuration just by copying that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `artifactory.config.xml` that's stored in your filesystem is there mainly for recovery scenarios, although it is perfectly usable, yes.
The thing is, is that you have to restart your instance to have the filesystem changes re-imported into Artifactory (you also need to rename the file to `artifactory.config.import.xml` for Artifactory to pick it up at startup).

If you're looking for and option to modify repository configuration (or any other [configuration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files) Artifactory has for that matter) during runtime you can use [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GeneralConfiguration) api which retrieves and [persists](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SaveGeneralConfiguration) the config.

It's perfectly safe to use as it represents all of the available configuration for all of your repos and the global configuration parameters as well.

Do take care though - it's always a good idea to backup a known working copy before you start playing around - there's no undo button.

Also, this configuration is subject to change as versions progress - you can always consult the [config schema](https://www.jfrog.com/public/xsd/artifactory-v1_7_3.xsd) if you get lost (note the version - that's the one you have at the top of the xml file declaration).